# @MapsId doesn't work with shared @EmbeddedId

Tags: hibernate, java-8, jpa-2.0, java-ee-7, payara

I have the following scenario here:

> a campaign contains many users. Each user is identified by a campaign id, an user id and his branch. Mapped as the following:

```java
@Entity
public class Campaign {

    @Id
    private Integer id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "campaign", cascade = ALL)
    private Set<UserByCampaign> usersByCampaign;

}
```

The  `UserByCampaign` class is defined this way:

```java
@Entity
public class UserByCampaign {

    @EmbeddedId
    private UserByCampaignPk id;

    @MapsId("userId")
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "FK_USER", referencedColumnName = "ID")
    private User user;

    @MapsId("campaignId")
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "FK_CAMPAIGN", referencedColumnName = "ID")
    private Campaign campaign;

    private String branch;

    @Embeddable
    public static class UserByCampaignPk implements Serializable {
        private Integer userId;
        private Integer campaignId;
    }
}
```

And also an `User` class:

```java
@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    private Integer id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
    private Set<UserByCampaign> usersByCampaign;

}
```

Of course I've suppressed the rest of the code to make it short.
Every time I try to persist a Campaign object with a bunch of User, it throws an Exception trying to insert a new User. It's needless to say that the exception's stack says that an user table unique constraint was violated.

```
INFO:   Hibernate: select SEQ_CAMPAIGN.nextval from dual
INFO:   Hibernate: insert into CAMPAIGN (...)
INFO:   Hibernate: insert into USER (STATUS, ID) values (?, ?)
WARN:   SQL Error: 1, SQLState: 23000
ERROR:   ORA-00001: unique constraint (SYS_C0083506) violated

INFO:   HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements
WARNING:   DTX5014: Caught exception in beforeCompletion() callback:
```

Removing `@MapsId` annotation and make both `@ManyToOne` mappings as `insertable=false` and `updatable=false` it works as desired.

I'm running a maven-based web application with Java SE8, JavaEE7 and Payara4.1.

**Edit:**

I was running it with Hibernate 4.3 but it also happens after updated to 5.2.10.Final.